# Проблема с типами QT 5.12.4

Tags: c++, qt

Есть такой код:

```
QByteArray  arrBlock;
        QDataStream out(&arrBlock, QIODevice::WriteOnly );
```

и такая ошибка

```
error: undefined reference to `QDataStream::QDataStream(QByteArray*, QIODevice::OpenModeFlag)'

error: no viable conversion from 'QIODevice::OpenModeFlag' to 'QIODevice::OpenMode' (aka 'QFlags<QIODevice::OpenModeFlag>')
```

что не так то? все по учебнику..

единственное это кросстул для nxp но я ж так понимаю что инклюды базовых классов для всех одинаковые

упд: чсх при этом приложение выпекается, а данная ошибка посвечивается не сплошной красной точкой, а красным кружком

Comment: Ошибка компиляции или clang анализатора, который надо отключить нахрен?

Comment: Ошибка компиляции

Answer (score 1):

При добавлении компилятора я указал тип кастом и указал пути к инклюдам, инклюды от кьют и инклюды с++ были в разных местах и подогнать их расположение под указанное в файлах кьюта оказалось дюже хлопотно, но зато если тип компилятора указать встроенный - например гцц сразу все ок.